# Nexus Jenkins Webhook Integration: Missing to trigger few webhooks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, nexus3

**Background**

I have a Jenkins job that does the resigning of android and ios apps based on the files uploaded to the Nexus repository.

I have 3 app versions for each android and ios.

Using nexus repo level [webhook triggering](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/webhooks) concept + [Jenkins generic Webhooks](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/) concept, we have achieved automated triggering of the builds when an app file is pushed to the nexus repository.

**Problem**

When all the 3 files are pushed in one go for any of the android or ios apps, can see only 2 Jenkins jobs webhook triggers only. one hook trigger is missing. Currently, we are seeing this issue very consistently.

The only observation that I have identified is, that whenever 3 files are pushed in one go, In the Jenkins job you see the webhook entry. see below screenshot of Jenkins job
[image]

I tried looking at multiple places but could not find a solution.

Any help here is appreciated...

Is there any possibility that we can count the number of webhooks received by the Jenkins job via code which we can see in the screenshot attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found similar issue reports in github.com: [#64](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/64) [#116](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/116) [#126](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/126) [#162](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/162) [#171](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/171).

After going through all these solutions, The solution which worked for me is:

- Uncheck the option "Disable Concurrent Builds" in Jenkins Job Configuration
- Parameterize the job
- Check options "Override Quiet Period" in Jenkins Job Configuration, under generic webhook configuration. [image: Override Quiet Period]
- you can pass the quiet period from the trigger point as mentioned in the above image.